# spring cloud app cannot connect with resource server

Tags: java, spring, redis, spring-boot, spring-cloud

In a simple spring cloud implementation, a `gateway` app on one server controls access to `ui` apps and `resource` apps running on other servers.  In the simplistic reproduction, the servers are modeled using different ports on localhost.  The `ui` can be loaded through the `gateway`, but the `resource` app throws a `500 error`, both then it is called through the `gateway` app at `localhost:8080/ui` and also when it is called through `localhost:9000`.  **How can I resolve this 500 error to get the resource app to load in the user's browser when called through the gateway app?**

I do not know if the problem is in the resource app itself, or in the Spring cloud config, or in the Spring session config, but I created a simple reproduction of the problem in three very simple apps, using the following explicit steps which can be reproduced easily on any machine:

---

**Create the Gateway App:**

---

First, I navigated the terminal to the root folder of an eclipse workspace, then I typed:

```
# mkdir gateway 
# chmod -R 777 gateway 
# cd gateway

# curl https://cloud-start.spring.io/starter.tgz -d style=web -d style=security -d style=cloud-zuul -d name=gateway -d style=redis | tar -xzvf -
```

I navigated to the root of the eclipse project again and typed `chmod -R 777 gateway` again.  Then I imported the new project into eclipse as follows:

```
Eclipse > File > Import > Existing Maven Project > (navigate to the gateway directory)
```

Next, I specified ZuulProxy and the running local Redis server by changing `GatewayApplication.java` to:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.EnableZuulProxy;
import org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.EnableRedisHttpSession;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableRedisHttpSession
@EnableZuulProxy
public class GatewayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GatewayApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

And I defined separate routes for `ui` and `resource`, and I also set up the gateway to handle authentication and sessions, by changing `src/main/resources/application.properties` to the following:

```
zuul.routes.ui.url: http://localhost:8081
zuul.routes.resource.url: http://localhost:9000
security.user.password: password
security.sessions: ALWAYS
```

---

**Creating the resource app:**

---

Then I created the resource app in the following steps.  First, I navigated the terminal to the root of the same eclipse workspace, and I typed in the following:

```
# mkdir resource 
# chmod -R 777 resource 
# cd resource

# curl https://start.spring.io/starter.tgz -d style=web -d name=resource -d language=java | tar -xzvf -
```

And I imported the auto-generated app into eclipse as follows:

```
Eclipse > Import > Existing Maven Project (navigate to resource folder just created)
```

And I added the following to `pom.xml` in the `resource` app:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

And I tried to connect the resrouce app to the running Redis server by changing `com.example.ResourceApplication.java` to the following:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.EnableRedisHttpSession;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class ResourceApplication {

  @RequestMapping("/resource")
  public Map<String,Object> home() {
    Map<String,Object> model = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    model.put("id", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    model.put("content", "Hello World");
    return model;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ResourceApplication.class, args);
  }

}
```

I configure the app to run on port 9000 and to never create its own sessions (thus deferring session management and authentication to the gateway, by putting the following in: `src/main/resources/application.properties`:

```
server.port: 9000
security.sessions: NEVER
```

Next, I navigate terminal to root directory of resource app and start the resource app by typing:

```
# mvn spring-boot:run
```

In a separate terminal window, I navigated to the root directory of the gateway app and also typed in:

```
# mvn spring-boot:run
```

And I created and launched the `ui` app in steps that I am happy to share, but that I am omitting here to keep this focused.  I think the error should be recreatable with the steps above by typing in the following two urls in the browser:

```
localhost:8080/resource
localhost:9000
```

**But BOTH of the above URLs cause 500 errors.**  The `ui` ap (not shown here) loads correctly in the browser when I type `localhost:8080/ui`, but the Firefox developer tools show the same `500 error` for the call to the `resource` app from within the `localhost:8080/ui` call.  I am omitting the `ui` app code because I think the problem can be recreated without it, and I want to keep this simple.

**So how do I change the code above to get the `resource` app to load correctly at `localhost:8080/resource`?**

Later on, I will worry about locking down direct access to the url and will make it accessible only to the ui app.  But for now, I want spring cloud, Redis and spring session to be able to handle authentication across servers.